# asyncio_redis and aioredis error on getting a list of keys

Tags: python-asyncio, asyncsocket, python-sockets

When I try to get values for a list of keys using asyncio_redis or aioredis, I am getting the following error. I know it is about something python socket, but unable to resolve the error. I attached both the code and error log with this issue. Here keys are a list of large byte arrays. **get_params_redis is called by multiple processes**. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
async def multi_get_key_redis(keys):
    redis = await aioredis.create_redis_pool(
        'redis://localhost')
    result =[]
    for key in keys:
        result.append(await redis.get(key))

        # assert result == await asyncio.gather(*keys)
        # return result
    redis.close()
    await redis.wait_closed()
    print(result)
    return result

def get_params_redis(shapes):
i = -1
params=[]
keys = []
for s in range(len(shapes)):
    keys.append(s)
values = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(multi_get_key_redis(keys))
for shape in shapes:
    i = i + 1
    param_np = pc._loads(values[i]).reshape(shape)
    param_tensor = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.from_numpy(param_np))
    params.append(param_tensor)
return params
```

Error Log:

```
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/srujithpoondla/largescaleml_project/train_redis.py", line 33, in train_redis
    train_redis_epoch(epoch, args, model, train_loader, optimizer,shapes_len, loop)
  File "/Users/srujithpoondla/largescaleml_project/train_redis.py", line 43, in train_redis_epoch
    params = get_params_redis(shapes_len,loop)
  File "/Users/srujithpoondla/largescaleml_project/common_functions.py", line 76, in get_params_redis
    params = loop.run_until_complete(multi_get_key_redis(keys))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 454, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 421, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1395, in _run_once
    event_list = self._selector.select(timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/selectors.py", line 577, in select
    kev_list = self._kqueue.control(None, max_ev, timeout)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: Did you try `await redis.mget(key1, key2)`?

Comment: Does your code use `multiprocessing`?

Comment: @andrew i tried await redis.mget(), still the same error :(

Comment: @sangmin yup, i am using multiprocessing.

Comment: Do you (re)create an event loop in forked process? Using a loop from parent is a error and could be the source of your problem.

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov thanks for the info! Is there any way to use asyncio.get in multiple processes? I am not using the loop from the parent process, I am creating a new one in every process. I edited the code and added few more lines.